# Scala - Difference between Stream.Cons[String] and scala.collection.immutable.Stream[String]

Tags: scala

Is there different between the Stream.Cons[String] and scala.collection.immutable.Stream[String] ?

Could you explain, as to me both seems to be same.

Thanks,
Revathy.